# Prevent overlapping of spawned game objects in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

Iam trying to make a simple 2d platformer game in unity. I managed to move the player and all other stuffs. The problem now i am facing is that the prefabs that randomly spawned onto the game is overlapping. So my question is how to prevent the overlapping of game objects. The prefabs i used is having different dimension(length).
Here is the c# code i used:

```
    public class spawnscript : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject[] obj;
    public float spawnMin;
    public float spawnMax;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Spawn ();
    }

    void Spawn()
    {
        Instantiate (obj [Random.Range (0, obj.GetLength (0))], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Invoke ("Spawn", Random.Range (spawnMin, spawnMax));
    }
}
```

[image: here is the screenshot of the game]

Comment: problem is with the buildings as in the pic

Comment: You need your spawning code to take into account the objects that have already been placed. Unfortunately, without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it will be very difficult to explain how to do that in a way that is helpful to you. You'll also need to be very clear on how you want to place objects, as that detail is missing from your question. Does it suffice to simply pick the object itself randomly, and to place them end-to-end along your game world? Or do you want some other placement/conflict-resolution behavior? Please be specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void Spawn() {
    Instantiate(obj [Random.Range (0, obj.GetLength (0))], transform.position +(ADD OFFSET HERE WITH PREVIOUS OBJECTS Position), Quaternion.identity);
    Invoke("Spawn", Random.Range (spawnMin, spawnMax));
}
```

Comment: Your Welcome , and keep making games:)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Vector3> existingPositions = new List<Vector3>();
void Spawn()
{
    var pos = RandomizePosition();
    if(HasOverlapped(existingPositions, pos)) // Your own logic to implement
    {
         //Either randomize the position again, or give it an offset, up to you
    }
    else
    {
        Instanciate(pos, ...);
        existingPositions.Add(...);
    }
}
```